# Why can't I use asterisks in my VirtualHost directive without avoiding a warning?

Tags: apache

I set up a virtual host for my django website.

```
NameVirtualHost 74.181.105.228:80
<VirtualHost 74.181.105.228:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com

# Run the SLMCS Django application.
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/david/djangosites/mydomain/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptReloading On

Alias /static/ /home/david/staticFiles/

<Directory /home/david/djangosites/mydomain>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

</Virtualhost>
```

If I change the second line to `<VirtualHost *:80>`, Apache issues a warning when I restart:

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost 74.181.105.228:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Why? Didn't I just set up a virtual host? The warning does not appear if I use `<VirtualHost 74.181.105.228:80>`.

Comment: hmm, somebody really does not like this question, lol, i wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error when do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Because you did not do this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

The argument to `NameVirtualHost` must match the string used in the `VirtualHost` block.

Comment: Thank you, strangely, replacing line 1 with `NameVirtualHost *:80` produces a similar warning: `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a NameVirtualHost line with a wildcard up top, like so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Basically, any address:port you plan to have in a `<VirtualHost address:port></VirtualHost>` directive will need to have a matching `NameVirtualHost` directive above it. Even if it's a wildcard.

Comment: Thank you, strangely, replacing line 1 with `NameVirtualHost *:80` produces a similar warning: `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`.

Comment: For any given unique `VirtualHost addr:port` you use, there should be a corresponding `NameVirtualHost addr:port` above it -- so if you're seeing that warning, it sounds like you may not have any `<VirtualHost *:80>` set up.

Comment: Thanks, I put `NameVirtualHost *:80` in apache2.conf and made `<VirtualHost *:80>` the first line of my virtual host in my `sites-available` folder. The warning oddly persists. I wonder why..